# What is the password?

Tags: password

You are a mechanic for McSmith Waterworks. You are called on site due to an emergency. A secret chamber has been discovered and some machinery in it has been activated. This machinery starts increasing the pressure of the water continuously, never stopping unless stopped internally (*very bad*).

At the entrance is a gate with a sign and several numbers (**The numbers are buttons**) below it. The sign says:

> Prime my pump backwards and enter!

Numbers:

```
            1
           2 3
          4 5 6
        7 8 9 10
       11 12 13 14
      15 16 17 18 19
     20 21 22 23 24 25
    26 27 28 29 30 31 32
   33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
  41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

Which buttons do you press and in which order?

"Hat tip to Stephen King"

Comment: Downvoted because there can be multiple valid answers, i.e. too broad.

Comment: @nikamed how so? the logic of the question takes in only 1 valid answer

Comment: @nikamed, the answer by Beastly Gerbil shows a very simple solution

Comment: The answer gives another reason to downvote. It's too simple.

Comment: @nikamed, I agree that it is simple, but sometimes the best questions are. Not sure about this one though :\

Comment: @AditKirtani well this is a complication...

Comment: @AditKirtani umm Flash quote? haha

Comment: @AditKirtani now complete I guess

Comment: The question really should say where it was taken from -- ie, Stephen King's *The Waste Lands*.

Comment: @DaphneB could I do that without spoiling everything?

Comment: You could put it in spoiler tags.  Or just say "Hat tip to Stephen King" and not name the book.

Comment: To demonstrate the point being made about it not having an unique valid answer, consider that you could just as easily consider a sequence such as 48, 47, 45, 43, 39, 37, 33... and so on. Or 3, 2, 5, 10, 14, 12, 17, 15... and so on. Both are just as legitimate a sequence given the sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7 , 5, 3 and 2 in that order

Because

> **Prime** my pump **backwards**, and you may enter?

Comment: yup this is right

Comment: Oh, this was a bit simple then